# Groupby a column and make a new column while aggregating over conditional statements

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I want to groupby color, count the number of occurrences of that color in a column and create a new column `within_range` which will have the count of cases where :
`min_amount <= amount <= max_amount`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red','yellow'], 
                   'amount': [0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.9, 0.8],
                   'min_amount': [0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7],
                   'max_amount':[1, 0.7, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9]})
```

Counting the number of occurrences can be done using:

`df.groupby('color').agg({'color':'count'})` but how to get the expected outcome?

Expected Result:

```
color         count    within_range
red             2            1
yellow          2            2
blue            1            1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need define the `within_range`series and groupby:

```
df['within_range'] = (df['amount'].le(df['max_amount']) 
                      & df['amount'].ge(df['min_amount'])
                     )

(df.groupby('color')['within_range']
   .agg(count='count',winthin_range='sum')
)
```

Output:

```
        count  winthin_range
color                       
blue        1            1.0
red         2            1.0
yellow      2            2.0
```

Comment: When I use 
`df['within_range'] = ((df['min_amount'] <= df['amount'] <= df['max_amount']))`,
I get the following error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`
Can I not do something like this if I don't want to use `&`?

Comment: No, I don't think you can do such with pandas series.